# How to list all users in the Cassandra shell?

Tags: cassandra, cql

In the CQL shell, how do I list all users? I can't seem to find it anywhere on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prior to the introduction of roles in Cassandra 2.2, authentication and authorization were based around the concept of a USER.

Cassandra 2.2 onward CQL uses database roles to represent users and group of users. So to list users use below command accordingly.

```
LIST USERS;  -- cassandra version < 2.2

LIST ROLES;  -- cassandra version >= 2.2
```

Answer (score 7):

From `CQL 3.x` LIST USERS command is **deprecated**.

You can retrieve users/roles with query:

```
SELECT * FROM system_auth.roles;
```

Ref: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlListUsers.html

Comment: are you sure about `all LIST commands` deprecation? only `LIST USERS` should be deprecated. Cassandra documentation says nothing about LIST ROLES: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/security.html#cql-roles

Answer (score 2):

You can do `LIST USERS;`

Output is:

```
 name      | super
-----------+-------
 cassandra |  True
     boone | False
     akers |  True
  spillman | False
```

See CQL for Apache Cassandra documentation - https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlListUsers.html

Comment: The documentation says it is deprecated - even as of v 3.3. Today in July 2022, it is version 6.